# Porque meu formulário não está aceitando acentos?

Tags: php, html, formulário

Criei um form com o php enviando os dados para o meu email, porém os dados que contém acentos ficam distorcidos e ruim para ler. Exemplo: "Teste rÃ¡pido nÃºmero 29"

Código PHP:

```html
$destinatario = "contato@meuemail.com";
$assunto = "FORMULARIO SITE";

$nome = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$telefone = $_REQUEST['fone'];
$mensagem = $_REQUEST['message'];


 // monta o e-mail na variavel $body

$body = "===================================" . "\n";
$body = $body . "CONTATO FORMULÁRIO DO SITE" . "\n";
$body = $body . "===================================" . "\n\n";
$body = $body . "Nome: " . $nome . "\n";
$body = $body . "telefone: " . $telefone . "\n";
$body = $body . "Email: " . $email . "\n";
$body = $body . "-----------------------------------" . "\n";
$body = $body . "Mensagem: " . $mensagem . "\n\n";
$body = $body . "===================================" . "\n";

// envia o email
mail($destinatario, $assunto , $body, "From: $email\r\n");


die( 'Sua Mensagem foi enviada. Obrigado!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um Header ao formulario do seu email e especificar a codificação do idioma, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
        $destinatario = "emaildestinatario@site.com";
        $remetente = "emailremetente@site.com";
        $subject = "Assunto do email";
        $mensagem = "Mensagem do email";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
        $headers .= "From: NOME DE QUEM ESTA ENVIANDO <" . $remetente . ">\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $remetente . "\n";
        
        mail($destinatario, $subject, $mensagem, $headers);
```

Se for mandar uma mensagem em HTML trocar o Content-type para text/html

Comment: Resolveu certinho, obrigado!